# Can i somehow retrieve the visibility-state of my view?

Tags: android, visibility, state

After setting the `myView` to `invisible`:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
myView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); }
```

can i somehow ask the current state of *myView's visibility* via some built-in-method?
something like *"myView.isVisible();"*

i checked android.developer, but didn't get an answer there.
thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
boolean visible = myView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
```

Comment: im pretty sure i already tried that and it didn't work. will try it again :)

Comment: thanks, it does work when i do it like you said.:   if (myView.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
    myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Answer (score 1):

`myView.isShown()`
Determines if this view and all of its parents have been set to visible.
However, it could be off screen (e.g. inside a `ViewPager`, `ScrollView`, etc) and `myView.isShown()` would still be `true`.

Instead, try this to determine if the `myView` is actually (partially) on the screen and shown to the user.

```
 Rect rect = new Rect();
 boolean visible = myView.isShown(); 
 boolean shown = visible && myView.getLocalVisibleRect(rect);
```

Comment: the last line checking if it is visible in general AND if its on the screen at the moment?#

Comment: Yes, that is what it does. And it updates 'rect' with the local coordinates of where it is shown (if it is shown).

Comment: You may not need the 'getLocalVisibleRect()' call for your needs and the call to isShown() could be more than enough. But that depends on your app. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the method as follow to know the visibility of view :

```
public String getVisibleState(View v) {
        if (v.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
            return "Visible";
        if (v.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
            return "In Visible";
        if (v.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            return "Gone";
        return "I dont know";
    }
```